# Getting the last viewed category on a product page?

Tags: category, session

We would like to add a link "view all other [category name] products" on the product page.

We tried several things no full success.

1. it seems there is a last viewed category methode `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getLastViewedCategoryId()` but this is always empty
2. and `Mage::registry('current_category')` is also empty
3. so we added a method to capture the breadcrumbs and get the before last item (this seems to work in some cases, but when the user opens some items directly or some Magento systems show the shortest path: then it results in "view all"

We are now testing a work around where we use setData to the session to store the category name and url whilst visting the category. We retrieve this on the product page. This seems to work in some cases also - but we use a FPC - so this code is not always executed.

What is the best - and always working - method to get the last visited category?

thanks in advance

Comment: you can create custome table in magento.when customer visit category page it will save value to table and display to product page

Answer (score -1):

You can try below code to get continue Shopping Category Url.

```
$lastProductIdAddedToCart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastAddedProductId();
if($lastProductIdAddedToCart) {
    $productCategoryIdsArray = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($lastProductIdAddedToCart)->getCategoryIds();
    //print_r($productCategoryIdsArray);    
    $continueShoppingCategoryUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(end($productCategoryIdsArray))->getUrl();
}
```

View the [source](http://ka.lpe.sh/2014/01/05/magento-continue-shopping-link-to-last-added-products-category-page/) for more details.